# How to access the nth item in a RecyclerView ListItem using Kotlin synthetic

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that contains ListItems as follows:

pagerecycler.xml:

```
  <com.tscriber.scriblett.views.PageRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/page_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/infinity_page_list_item" />
```

infinity_page_list_item.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/memo_page_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/memo_page_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Using Kotlin synthetics, from the parent fragment I can turn those ListItem ImageViews visible or invisible using `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.infinity_page_list_item.*` and `memo_page_image?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE`.

But that synthetic only turns the ImageView in the **first** ListItem invisible. Is it possible to turn the ImageView in the **nth** ListItem on and off using synthetics? Something like `memo_page_image[2]?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE`, but not that because that doesn't work.

I don't have to use synthetics, of course. If it's not possible with synthetics, how do I do it some other way?

I've mucked around with arrays of ListAdapter callbacks in the past, but that always felt like a kludge to me so I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it.

thanks in advance

John

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are asking. I think I know the solution, what is the event that dictates visibility though? That will help me explain how to do this. By event, I mean button click or user action or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

in recyclerView ViewHolder, Using Kotlin synthetic, just try this:

itemView.memo_page_image?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

Comment: So that would be 'mViewManager.findViewByPosition(2).memo_page_image?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE'? Unfortunately that doesn't build.

Comment: But this does: mViewManager.findViewByPosition(2)?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.memo_page_image)?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
If you tweak your answer I will mark it correct. Thanks! Who needs synthetics anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin synthetics are for `ViewBinding` only . It make the ugly `findViewById()` goes away and cache the view to prevent multiple calls for finding the view(like in an Adapter View) . SO it does not play any role in `RecyclerAdapter` Configuration.
If you want to change n'th item in a `RecyclerView` you can not just use `findViewByPosition()` cause it will return null if nth item is not visible on screen.
 So as a full proof Solution you just change in your dataset for this particular position(maybe a boolean whether to show or not true/false) and then just use `notifyItemChanged(postion)` and handle it inside `onBindViewHolder()`. Something like below:-

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if(show){
        memo_page_image?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        memo_page_image?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```